# REGEXP_EXTRACT in google data studio

Tags: regex, looker-studio, re2

I'm trying to generate 3 new calculated fields in Google Data Studio / Looker Studio using the `REGEXP_EXTRACT` function.

Here is the sample data that I have on a Google sheet:

| Sample data |
| --- |
| Serviços de Impressão > Impressoras > Falha na impressão > Troca de Tonner |
| Aplicativos e Softwares > Avaliação de Aplicativos e Software > Pacote Office |
| Computadores e Periféricos > Manutenção > Teclado / Mouse > Aquisição de equipamento |
| Acessos > Certificado Digital |

Each  `>`   represents a division and ideally what I would like to do is extract the first three fields and disregard the rest, something like this:

| Calculated field 1 | Calculated field 2 | Calculated field 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Serviços de Impressão | Impressoras | Falha na impressão |
| Aplicativos e Softwares | Avaliação de Aplicativos e Software | Pacote Office |
| Computadores e Periféricos | Manutenção | Teclado / Mouse |
| Acessos | Certificado Digital | null |

I managed to generate a code to extract the first calculated field using

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Sample data,'^(.+?)>')
```

but in the second I didn't know how to do it, since I can always have one or more separators  `>`  as in the example of the last line.

How can I formulate the codes for calculated fields 2 and 3 please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second field can be extracted with

```sql
 > (.*?)(?: > |$)
```

The third field - if any - can be obtained with

```
 > .*? > (.*?)(?: > |$)
```

The `(?: > |$)` non-capturing group matches either space + `>` + space, or end of string.

Comment: Hi Wiktor, what if I wanted to get everything up to the third > sign? in the example of the last line get the whole line since I only have 2 fields.

Comment: @CarolineReginaldoTorres Use `^((?:.*? > ){2}.*?) > `, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3s4moZ/1).

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(test1,'^(?:[^>]+>){0}([^>]+)')
```

the above formula is for the first field. ***change the Zero in parentheses*** to 1 for second field and 2 for third field.

[image]

Comment: Worked great! I just needed to add a TRIM fuction after to clean the extra spaces. Thank you!